# Cannot convert 'System.String' to 'System.Int32' Error in SSIS Expression Builder

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm getting an error every time I evaluate this expression in my Expression builder. I'm getting a Cannot convert 'System.String' to 'System.Int32'. Anyone knows why it does so?

```
"
INSERT INTO lgs_FOS_Extract_Errors VALUES('"+ @[System::MachineName] +"','"+ @[System::PackageName] +"'," +(DT_WSTR, 12)@[System::ErrorCode]+ ",'"+ @[System::ErrorDescription] +"',GETDATE())
"
```

I tried to one by one remove every values but I can't find where the error coming from. I am expecting to find the write expression for my SQL task

Comment: So if you remove all the variables, does it work? What ifg you add one by one? BTW an `INSERT` statement should always have a column list like this `INSERT INTO <table> (column1, column2) VALUES (value1,value2)`